# phpmyadmin whitescreen

Tags: phpmyadmin

To install my LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04 I followed these instructions [Here](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

With the exception of installing php 5.6 instead of 7.0 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

phpmyadmin then threw an error saying mbstring was missing so I installed

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

now all I get is a white screen when trying to access phpmyadmin

After trying to access phpmyadmin I get this in the apache2 error log

```
[Sun Sep 18 21:20:51.306056 2016] [:error] [pid 21053] [client 127.0.0.1:34158] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
```

Comment: I had previously followed those instructions on a separate installation with php7 and everything worked fine.

Comment: Have you checked your Apache error log? `tail /var/logs/apache2/error_log`

Answer (score 1):

After checking the Apache error log that TriG so kindly recommended I ended up installing

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

and it works fine now